# Android Animation Increase Height of ImageButton

Tags: android, animation, android-imagebutton

Could someone let me know how to animate an image button so the height increases?
Any examples that I have read scale the height of the button. 
I just want the top of the bottom to increase in height when clicked. I don't want the buttons position to move, just click the button and the height increases.
Heres my code

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:src="@drawable/iman"
    android:maxHeight="50dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp" />

findViewById(R.id.buttton).setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animator scale = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(v,
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1,             1.5f, 1)
            );
            scale.setDuration(1000);
            scale.start();
        }
    });
```

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Can you post your layout file containing this button

Answer (score 1):

U can achive your effect like this:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        v.startAnimation(new Animation() {
            private int mStartHeight;
            private int mEndHeight;

            @Override
            public void initialize(final int width, final int height, final int parentWidth, final int parentHeight) {
                mStartHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
                mEndHeight = 600;

                setDuration(300);
            }

            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(final float interpolatedTime, final Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (mStartHeight + (interpolatedTime * (mEndHeight - mStartHeight)));
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.@BasilMiller
However, this does not give me the desired affect. This is basically the same as scaling. The height of the button increases at the top and bottom.
I am only looking for the top of the button to increase in height only.
In other words the xposition of the bottom of the button should not increase. Only the top of the button should expand?

Comment: If i use view.settop this gives me the desired effect. 
So how can I implement that into an animation?

Comment: Try to align_bottom your view and the height will be measured to top.